# Using Facebook Comments Social Plugin — Many non related comments for newly created page

Tags: facebook

I'm in the process of creating a new website and I just added the FB comments Social app to my posts, but I keep seeing comments that are not related to the article and they date weeks before I've even created the page. What is wrong here?

[image: Using Facebook Comments Social Plugin — many Facebook users comments aren't Public]

Comment: _“What is wrong here?“_ - most likely the URL you associated the comments with …

Comment: I've added the right domain and nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. I just needed to change the data-href value to be the permalink of my website. it looks like this: `data-href=“<?php the_permalink(); ?>”`